# PHP Namespace Questions

Tags: php, namespaces

Hey I am new to php namespaces and I'm trying to make sense of something. I am following the `PRO Php MVC e-book` and they use a lot of namespace examples in there code. What's confusing me is the difference between `\Framework\Name` and `Framework\Name`?

When do you use which version and what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its really a difference of where its being used in the code.

For example, in a `use` statement, either can be used:

```
<?php
namespace Framework;

use Framework\Name;
// OR
use \Framework\Name;
// Both do the same thing
```

However, when you are actually in the code, not having the `\` in the front of the namespace, will make the code look in the current namespace for the file. Example:

```
<?php
namespace Framework;
// ...
// The below will actually look for the class `\Framework\Framework\Name`
$class = new Framework\Name();
// However, this will look for, and hopefully find `\Framework\Name`
$class = new \Framework\Name();
```

This lets you do things like have a use statement on a subnamespace, and shorten your calls in the code: Example

```
<?php
namespace Framework;
use Framework\Cache;

class test {
    public function __construct() {
        // Below gets `\Framework\Cache\Memcache`
        $memcache = new Cache\Memcache();
        // Below gets `\Framework\Cache\Apc`
        $apc = new Cache\Apc();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!