# PHP Namespace conventions - doubling namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

From time to time I keep seeing doubled namespaces something like:
`Namespace/Namespace/Subnamespace/`

For example new Prestashop (1.7) uses this convention
`namespace PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core;`

Could someone explain me benefits of this type of namespacing?

Also some tutorials say about namespacing like this:

```
namespace mynamespace/classname
classs classname {}
```

What are benefits of this? Cause I only see disadvantages as: more complicated namespaces and more typing.

Also saw this Q&A: [PHP Namespace Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575071/php-namespace-questions)
I can see only disadvantage: more prone to bugs as it depends on *relative namespacing*

PS: I keep on using always absolute namespaces. It's less prone to bugs in my feeling, enlighten me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: They're following [psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). There's nothing wrong with the namespace itself, but I can see how it can be confusing.

Comment: @Andrew I was writing up an answer that goes along the line of PSR-4 but there does not seem to be anything that requires that sub-name space. Is this just a creators choice? Does it stem from PSR-0?

Comment: @nerdlyist I assume it's creators choice and that's the only thing I can do, assume.

Comment: PSR-4 would be for 2nd part of question I assume. namespace/classname;

Comment: From what I see in PSR-4 it does not require to use ``namespace\tools`` for ``tools`` class. As it would be stupid since it would require each class have its own namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned this is for auto-loading and follows PSR-4 conventions. The naming convention for Namespaces is generally left up to the creator. The only required piece is the top level namespace but there can be many sub-namespaces used if wanted.

For example in PrestaShop's `composer.json` they have:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "PrestaShop\\PrestaShop\\": "src/",
        "PrestaShopBundle\\": "src/PrestaShopBundle/"
    }
}
```

So the namespace `PrestaShop\PrestaShop\` can get you to any thing within `src`.

In the `slim` framework (a router) they have:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Slim\\": "Slim"
    }
}
```

So in that one you just use the namespace `Slim\Class`.

In one of my first project I did something like:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Models\\": "app_name/models",
        "App\\Validators\\": "app_name/validators"
        //And so on
    }
}
```

I do not think this hurts anything but redundant in the end.